# Is spreading an array_like object equivalent to Array.prototype.slice.call(array_like)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Some information on how spread operators works would be great. Does it have anything to do with the new Symbol introduced in ES2015?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has nothing to do with Symbol, except that the `Iterable` symbol is needed for an object to work with spread syntax. And it isn't equivalent to the `Array.prototype.splice` call, though you probably meant `Array.prototype.slice()`, which is just for making a shallow copy of an array-like object.

It's *a little bit* similar to using `.apply` to call a function, passing a collection as the second argument, which gets spread out as individual arguments. However, unlike `.apply()`, you can use multiple collections (with multiple "spreads"), and you can pass other arguments before and after the spread ones.

Also, with `.apply()` any array-like object works (has numeric indexes and a `.length`) though in ES3 only Arrays and Arguments objects worked. But the spread syntax only works with Iterable objects.